# Expression for $B_1$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I think that it is indeed the case that
$$
B_1 = \int_0^1 \frac{B_1 - B_t}{1-t} dt,
$$
where $B$ is a standard one-dimensional Brownian motion.

Am I right? If so, how you we prove it?

Thanks a lot

Tom

Comment: Why do you think so? Already the variances do not seem to agree...

Comment: There is a similar formula which you can obtain through an enlargement of filtration argument. That formula is $B_1 = W_1 + \int_0^1 \frac{B_1 - B_t}{1-t}dt$, where $W_t$ is Brownian motion with respect to the filtration of $B_t$ enlarged by $\sigma(B_1)$.  I do not know whether or not that is what you are looking for.